# Не совсем правильно работает функция определения id с помощью jquery

Tags: jquery, php, css

И снова я со своим jquery) Может не совсем правильно написал заголовок, но дело, в общем, такое - есть у меня две странички. На первой выводится только одна последняя новость из БД, на второй несколько. При выводе новостей (что на первой странице, что на второй) генерируется "оберточный" блок, в котором находится эта новость с такими, эм.. как бы это назвать.. параметрами чтоли. Короче говоря див такой:

```
<div class="news" id="post_<?=$row['id']?>">
```

И потом в новости есть ссылка вида:

```
<a href="#" id="moren">Показать всю новость</a>
```

Что у меня работает:
На первой странице, как я уже сказал, выводится одна новость. По клике на ссылку происходит поиск её родителя по id (т.е. post_1/2/3 и т.д.), выдирается этот самый id, и дальше "открывается" другое окно, в которое копируется содержимое дива и добавляется с помощью ajax дополнительная, так сказать, фулл новость из БД по этому же ID что и "маленькая" новость.
В общем для одной новости это работает. На второй странице в цикле выведены новости так:

```
<div class="news" id="post_5">
...//тело новости
<div class="more"><a href="#" id="moren">Показать всю новость</a></div>
</div>

<div class="news" id="post_4">
...//тело новости
<div class="more"><a href="#" id="moren">Показать всю новость</a></div>
</div>

<div class="news" id="post_3">
...//тело новости
<div class="more"><a href="#" id="moren">Показать всю новость</a></div>
</div>
```

И при клике на новость "5" всё нормально открывается "окошко" как и на странице с одной новостью, а при клике на остальные ничего не происходит, только подставляется в адресную строчку # и страница, естественно, "улетает" вверх. Почему так, не совсем понимаю.
Вот код, который это делает (ВНИМАНИЕ - множество костылей и быдлокода присутствуют здесь. Просьба не ругаться, я ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО переделаю этот код под более красивый, когда научусь! Правда:) ):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#moren').click(function(e){
     var $message = $('#fullnewswrap');
     var idfull = this.parentNode.parentNode.id //$(this).parent().parent().attr('id')
     var idfullarr = new Array();
     idfullarr = idfull.split('_');
     var id = idfullarr[1];

    if ($message.css('display') != 'block') {
       $message.show();

        if (!$('.container').text()) {
            alert ('Контейнер был пуст!');
            cloneNews(id);  
        } else if ($('.container>h1').text() != $('#post_'+id+'>h1').text()) {
            alert ('У контейнера была другая запись. Делаю новую!');
            $('.container').empty();
            cloneNews(id);
        } else { alert ('Контейнер имеет одну и ту же запись, ничего не трогаем, просто показываем заново'); }
        var firstClick = true; //Отсюда и до конца этой функции код скопипастен с инета - убирает всплывшее окно при клике вне его. 
    $(document).bind('click.myEvent', function(e) {
        if (!firstClick && $(e.target).closest('.container').length == 0) {
            $message.hide();
            $(document).unbind('click.myEvent');
        }
        firstClick = false;
    });
} 
e.preventDefault();
});
});

function cloneNews(id) {
var nheader = $('#post_'+id+'>h1').clone(); //пока не знаю, как сделать НЕ в три строчки и чтобы правильно работало. 
var nDT = $('#post_'+id+'>.postDT').clone();
var ntext = $('#post_'+id+'>.text').clone();
$('.container').append(nheader).append(nDT).append(ntext);  
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"/engine/fullnews.php",
    data:{"id":id},
    cache: false,
    success: function(fullNews){ 
        $('.container').html($('.container').html()+'<div class="textfull">'+fullNews+'</div>');
    }
})
};
```

Уже во многом Вы мне отлично помогли, не укажете на ошибку в очередной раз? Если я забыл чего ещё добавить нужного для понимания, спрашивайте.

Comment: рекомендую вам прислушаться к советам @xEdelweiss :)

Comment: С кодом согласен, переборщил, просто торопился, уйти нужно было. И так там покрамсал его, лишнего боялся убрать:) Ну да ладно, конечно буду убирать в другой раз. Про ID действительно как-то не подумал, сделаю класс, отпишусь, что вышло.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, с классом работает прекрасно:)

Comment: @DizzWebS, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).  
Преобразовал в ответ, чтобы было виднее.

Comment: @xEdelweiss хорошо, что преобразовали, без ответа я не мог его как верный пометить, естественно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ID элемента не должно повторяться на странице, это ведь ID. Вешайте клик на `.more`. Это как минимум.
На будущее, постарайтесь удалять код, который работает и не очень то и относится к ошибке. Так, например, узнайте какую новость пытается открыть скрипт, если проблема в этом - убираете саму загрузку из вопроса. И т.п.